# I am trying to pass the range of number in index from 0 - 100 or if I have n number then 0 to n. how do I do that in cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

Given I launch the url ""
When I login with username and password from ""

```
 Examples:
   |RowNumber|
   |0      |
   |1      |
   |2      |
```

When I pass individual rows, code is fetching from excel and executing fine.
But I had 1000's of excel data , which I need to pick few set of data and need to run, In this case, how I can achieve to give range under examples?
Examples:
|RowNumber|
|0-2      |, where it should execute for all the rows?
can anyone please help me?

package stepdefinitions;

public class SeleniumStepDefs extends PageObjectLoader {

```
private List<String> getValuesFromExcel(String rowRange, String columnName) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "D:\\Kiran\\Tarrif.xls";
    String sheetName = "Sheet1";
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> rowNumbers = getRowNumbersFromRange(rowRange);
    for (String rowNumber : rowNumbers) {
        String value = getValueFromExcel(rowNumber, columnName, sheet);
        values.add(value);
        System.out.println("The value of the rowRange parameter is: " + rowRange);
        System.out.println("The contents of the Excel file are: " + values);
    }

    workbook.close();
    fileInputStream.close();

    if (values.isEmpty()) {
        // If no values are found in the Excel file, handle the error case appropriately
        throw new IOException("No values found in the Excel file for the specified range: " + rowRange + ", column: " + columnName);
    }

    return values;
}

private String getValueFromExcel(String rowNumber, String columnName, Sheet sheet) throws IOException {
    int rowIndex = Integer.parseInt(rowNumber) - 1; // Adjusting to 0-based index
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
    if (row != null) {
        int columnIndex = getColumnIndex(sheet, columnName);
        if (columnIndex != -1) {
            Cell valueCell = row.getCell(columnIndex);
            if (valueCell != null) {
                valueCell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                return valueCell.getStringCellValue();
            }
        }
    }
    // If the value is not found in the Excel file, handle the error case appropriately
    throw new IOException("Value not found in the Excel file for row: " + rowNumber + ", column: " + columnName);
}

private int getColumnIndex(Sheet sheet, String columnName) {
    Row headerRow = sheet.getRow(0);
    for (Cell cell : headerRow) {
        if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING && cell.getStringCellValue().equals(columnName)) {
            return cell.getColumnIndex();
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private List<String> getRowNumbersFromRange(String rowRange) {
    List<String> rowNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] range = rowRange.split("-");
    int startRow = Integer.parseInt(range[0].trim());
    int endRow = Integer.parseInt(range[1].trim());

    if (startRow <= endRow) {
        for (int row = startRow; row <= endRow; row++) {
            rowNumbers.add(String.valueOf(row));
        }
    } else {
        rowNumbers.add(rowRange);
    }

    return rowNumbers;
}

private Sheet sheet; // Declare the sheet as a member variable
```

// ...

```
private void initializeSheet() throws IOException {
    String filePath = "D:\\Kiran\\Tarrif.xls";
    String sheetName = "Sheet1";
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    fileInputStream.close();
    workbook.close();
}

@Given("I launch the PegaEE url {string}")
public void iLaunchThePegaEEUrl(String rowRange) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    initializeSheet(); // Initialize the sheet object
    List<String> rowNumbers = getRowNumbersFromRange(rowRange);
    for (String rowNumber : rowNumbers) {
        String url = getValueFromExcel(rowNumber, "URL", sheet);
        System.out.println(url);
        BaseStepDefs.scenario.log(url);
        pegaBausitLoginPage.openPegaLoginPage(url);
        captureScreenshots.captureScreenshotInByte();
    }
}

@When("I login with username and password from {string}")
public void iLoginWithUsernameAndPasswordFrom(String rowRange) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    initializeSheet(); // Initialize the sheet object
    List<String> rowNumbers = getRowNumbersFromRange(rowRange);
    for (String rowNumber : rowNumbers) {
        String username = getValueFromExcel(rowNumber, "username", sheet);
        BaseStepDefs.scenario.log("Entered text " + username + " in the username Text Box");
        String password = getValueFromExcel(rowNumber, "password", sheet);
        BaseStepDefs.scenario.log("Entered text " + password + " in the password Text Box");
        pegaBausitLoginPage.pegaLogin(username, password);
        captureScreenshots.captureScreenshotInByte();
    }
}
```

**Feature File:**
Scenario Outline: Tariff Sample _ BPREPEE
Given I launch the PegaEE url ""
When I login with username and password from ""
Examples:
|rowRange|
|1-3     |
Getting Step failed
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
(Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.199)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'BWT14722007', ip: '10.54.34.173', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.14'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 114.0.5735.199, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f..., userDataDir: C:\Users\PC986682\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:60588}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 4062fafe0ec0512248f6889441054007